# Angular 4 Unable to Get Cookies From Header Response

Tags: angular, cookies

I'm trying to get cookies from header response in Angular 4.I have written AuthenticationService in which i am calling cookies based authentication api of Pentaho.Now i want to get Set-Cookies from header after click on the login button.on browser console i am able to see the Response header but unable to get.can any one suggest any idea how i can resolve this problem.

Login Component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../service/authentication.service';
import { LoginInformationModel } from './logininformationdatamodel';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
   providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  model: any = {};
  loading = false;
    error = '';
  constructor(  private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      }
login()  {
       this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.j_username, this.model.j_password)
            .subscribe(
                                res => { console.log("Success:");},
                               error => {
                                    console.log("Error:");
                                     this.loading = false;

                                }
                            );
    }

}
```

AuthenticationService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams  } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import "rxjs/Rx"
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
   }

  login(j_username: string, j_password: string): Observable<any> {

     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        urlSearchParams.append('j_username', j_username);
        urlSearchParams.append('j_password', j_password);
        let body = urlSearchParams.toString()
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        //return this.http.post('http://localhost:8083/pentaho/j_spring_security_check', body, {headers:headers})
          //.map(res => res.json())withCredentials: true
          return this.http.post('http://localhost:8083/pentaho/j_spring_security_check', body, options)
             //.map(response => response.headers);
        .map((res) => { res.json(); console.log('ma-ta'); })
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.message)); 

 }

}
```

Comment: Try changing your `map` in the service to `.map((res) => { return res.json(); })`

Comment: nothing just getting-> error occurs  login.component.ts:28:12
undefined

Comment: I think may be some mistake in Login Component that why when i click on login button then always going on error section and displaying console on error -occur..?...i am unable to find that .